# Elasticsearch first query is slow, rest of them are fast

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using this kind of mapping (well, it's a shortener version in order to make the question easier) on a children-parent relationship where `item` is the parent and `user_items` is the children.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/myindex?pretty=true' -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "items": {
       "dynamic": "strict",
       "properties" : {
            "title" : { "type": "string" },
            "body" : { "type": "string" },
}},
    "user_items": {
      "dynamic": "strict",
      "_parent": {"type": "items" },
      "properties" : {
            "user_id" : { "type": "integer" },
            "source_id" : { "type": "integer" },
}}}}'
```

And the type of query I usually make:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/myindex/items/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
    "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "query_string": {
                  "fields": ["title", "body"],
                  "query": "mercado"
               }
            },
            {
               "has_child": {
                  "type": "user_items",
                  "query": {
                     "term": {
                        "user_id": 655
    }}}}]}}}'
```

On this query it has to search on the fields `title` and `body` the string `mercado` on a given `user_id`, in this case `655`.

I read that the reason of being so slow the first query is that it gets cacheed and then the rest queries are fast because it works with the cached content.

I read I can make the first query faster using **[eager](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/preload-fielddata.html)** to preload my data (using `"loading" : "eager"`, right?) but I dont know what do I've to preload. Do I've to use the `earger` on `title` and `body` as follows?

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "items": {
       "dynamic": "strict",
       "properties" : {
            "title" : { "type": "string" ,
                        "fielddata": {
                            "loading" : "eager"}},
            "body" : { "type": "string",
                        "fielddata": {
                            "loading" : "eager"}},
}},
    "user_items": {
      "dynamic": "strict",
      "_parent": {"type": "items" },
      "properties" : {
            "user_id" : { "type": "integer" },
            "source_id" : { "type": "integer" },
}}}}'
```

Any other recommendation fot boosting/cacheeing the first query is welcome. Thanks in advance

PS: I'm using ES 2.3.2 under a Linux machine and I've a total of 25.396.369 documents.

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: You can use warmers, but first make sure that it's not swapping. What OS are you running ES on?

Comment: @Val  2.3.2 and I'm using Linux.

Comment: @AndreKR [warmers are deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/indices-warmers.html) as of 2.3.0 and will go away in ES 5.

Comment: @AndreKR warmers are deprecated. That was the first thing I read.

Comment: Run `vmstat 1` and watch the `si` number during your first query. It should be low, ideally 0.

Comment: Yes, it's 0 all the time, @AndreKR

Comment: @AndreKR The only thing that changes while indexing is the `bo` value (blocks sent to a block device), which changes from `0` to `52`

Comment: I got the same issue except with 100 million records and a 24 cpu machine, 64GB memory with 31G for elasticsearch heap and swap disabled. The initial search is always slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just fixed the same issue. Field Data preloading was the key. Index warming was deprecated and doc_values is on by default. My application searched a couple fields on a large index (100G+) and was slow I had to rebuild the index with loading=eager for all of the fields that I searched on. This preloads it and causes a pretty long startup but after that search went from initial of 10s (<400ms afterwards) to <900ms initial search (<400ms afterwards). Make the mapping and reimport the data

```
PUT localhost:9200/newindex/
{
  "mappings": {
    "items": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string",
          "fielddata": {
            "loading" : "eager"
          }
        },
        "body": {
          "type": "string",
          "fielddata": {
            "loading" : "eager"
          }
        }
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are three things you can do.

1. **Use field data preloading**
   To preload field data use following snippet in mapping

   "fielddata": {
         "loading" : "eager" 
       }
   More details [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/preload-fielddata.html)
2. **Use index warmer**
   Index warmers are certain queries that you can configure which will run automatically whenever a index is refreshed.
   [This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-warmers.html) link contains details on how to set up a warmer.
3. **Use doc_values**
   Doc values are the on-disk data structure, built at document index time, which makes data access pattern possible for aggregation and sorting possible.
   Find more details [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/doc-values.html)

Comment: I've already read the docs. I'm asking for a solution for my exact problem.

Comment: Have you tried making user_id and source id also as fielddata eager? If that doesn't work either, please try using doc_values, you can turn it on by making `"doc_values": false` on each property. i had a similar issue we have solved it using doc_values. first query for us used be pretty slow.

Comment: Now index warmer are deprecated as there is a lot of improvement on indexation v5.x